# How to configure network interface with chef ifconfig resource for IP determined at recipe runtime

Tags: networking, chef, opsworks

I'm working with Chef through Amazon Opsworks and need to provision and configure additional network interfaces for some of my servers, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly use the `ifconfig` chef resource.  The primary problem is that I don't know the IP address for the interface at the time I'm writing the chef recipe.  All the examples I've seen show the target IP address expressed as a constant string in the resource name like so:

```
ifconfig '10.0.0.1' do
 eth1
end
```

However, I am provisioning the network interface at time of the execution of the recipe, so I don't know beforehand what IP address the provisioned network interface will be assigned in within the local network (Amazon VPC).  I've written a ruby_block resource that provisions the interface and gathers the assigned IP, but I get errors from the chef resource when I try to pass it to the `ifconfig` resource as the documentation seems to suggest I should.  My code looks similar to the following:

```
ruby_block 'provision_and_get_IP' do
  # Inside the following function the AWS CLI is called to provision
  # a network interface and return the assigned IP address
  assigned_ip = provision_and_get_ip()
  node["my_attributes"]["assigned_ip"] = assigned_ip
end

ifconfig 'setup_interface' do
  device 'eth1'  
  target lazy { node["my_attributes"]["assigned_ip"] }
end
```

And I get an error that reads

```
[2016-03-30T19:15:21+00:00] ERROR: ifconfig[setup_interface] (my_cookbook::my_recipe line 66) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: ifconfig eth1 setup_interface returned 1, expected 0
---- Begin output of ifconfig eth1 setup_interface ----
STDOUT: STDERR: setup_interface: Unknown host
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
---- End output of ifconfig eth1 setup_interface ----
```

The [documentation for the ifconfig resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ifconfig.html) seemed to suggest that the target property just defaults to the name of the resource and that if I set it this would work, but that seems to not be the case.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to achieve much with `ifconfig` recipe here. When you request additional interface for your VM it is allocated by Amazon and I think addressing is managed by Amazon as well. Even if you are able to change IP address of your interface there is a good chance it will not be recognized and routed properly by Amazon.

One of the options is to use private static IP addresses that you actually know the address your interface will receive ahead of time. Another option would be to extract address of the new interface from metadata.